# Is there a better way to test this Rails controller with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have an Account model that validates that its subdomain is unique.

I'm trying to learn how to test controllers with RSpec.

Here's what I've come up with, but it's quite different than the generated RSpec test and i'm wondering if this is a good way to test this or if there's a better way.

My test:

```
describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Account" do
        original_count = Account.count
        account = FactoryGirl.build(:account, :subdomain => 'newdomain')
        post :create, {:account => account}
        account.save!
        new_count = Account.count
        expect(new_count).to eq(original_count + 1)
      end
...
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to point out the fact that in my spec_helper I have the code below. It is needed because of the way i'm handling subdomains:

```
config.before(:each, :type => :controller) do
    @account = FactoryGirl.create(:account)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @request.host = "#{@account.subdomain}.example.com"
    sign_in @user
end
```

Comment: I either haven't gotten these to work or haven't gotten back to this yet.

Answer (score 4):

There is, by using Rspec's [`expect to change`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change), and FactoryGirl's [`attributes_for`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) (might need tweaking, not tested):

```
describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Account" do
        expect{
          post :create, { account: attributes_for(:account) }
        }.to change{Account.count}.by(1)
      end
...
```

Validate your unique subdomain constraint in your unit tests, perhaps using [`shoulda-matchers`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#validate_uniqueness_of):

```
describe Account do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:subdomain) }
end
```

Comment: I have a model test which validates my unique constraint.

Comment: @Catfish then by validating unique constraint in the controller, you are only testing that `subdomain` param is passed to the model.

Comment: So are you saying that i do or do not need the validate uniqueness in my controller since I have it in my model? I'm not quite following. Also, your test does not work. It causes this error: `Failure/Error: expect {
       expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`. Also note that I updated my question with a before(:each) that i have in my spec helper which probably contributes to my test failing somehow.

Comment: `post :create, { account: attributes_for(:account, :subdomain => 'newdomain') }` also does not work. Gives the same error.

Comment: @Catfish my test is not to be used as-is. It is an example. You'll have to do the rest of the leg work yourself. Does your factory for `Account` return a static `subdomain`? It could be failing because of the unique constraint, as you've already created an `Account` in your `before(:each)` block.

Comment: It shouldn't be failing with the subdomain unique constraint if I explicitly set a different subdomain than what exists in my Account factory right?

Comment: @Catfish no, it shouldn't. Might be worth using a sequence for your subdomain, though. -- https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage#sequences-and-associations

Answer (score 0):

I would make a controller spec a true unit test and not involve the database. Something like:

```
describe AccountsController do
  describe '#create' do
    it "creates a new Account" do
      account_attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for :account
      expect(Account).to receive(:create!).with account_attrs
      post :create, account: account_attrs
     end
  end
end
```

I'd also have a feature spec (or a Cucumber scenario) that integration-tested the entire interaction of which the post to `AccountsController` was a part. Actually if I had a happy-path feature spec/scenario there would be no need to write the controller spec above, but I'd need controller specs for error paths (like trying to create an `Account` with the same subdomain as an existing `Account`) and other variations and I'd write them similarly to the spec above, by stubbing and mocking database calls.